# trying to measure the diameter of a golf ball using regionprops from image-proc toolbox

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, image-processing, binary-image

I wrote a program that takes an image of a golf ball,
processing it to create a binary image that represents only the ball in white and
the rest of the picture (background) in black.
I want to use the built-in function regionprops to calculate the diameter of the golf ball.
[image: this is the picture of the golf ball]

my code:

```
img = imread("golf2.jpg");

%% part 1
img_R = img(:,:,1);
img_G = img(:,:,2);
img_B = img(:,:,3);

figure (1)
subplot(2,2,1); imshow(img);
title('original image');
subplot(2,2,2); imshow(img_R);
title('R plane image');
subplot(2,2,3); imshow(img_G);
title('G plane image');
subplot(2,2,4); imshow(img_B);
title('B plane image');

figure(2)
imhist(img_B)

%% part 2
img_grayscale = imadjust(img_B);
[row, col] = size(img_grayscale);
for i = 1:row
    for j = 1:col
        if (img_grayscale(i,j) < 100) 
            img_grayscale(i,j) = 0;
        else
            img_grayscale(i,j) = 255;
        end
    end
end
figure(3)
imshowpair(img_grayscale, img_B, 'montage')

%% part 3
BW = img_grayscale;
fill = imfill(BW, 'holes');
figure; imshow(fill)
se = strel('disk', 10);
open = imopen(fill,se);
figure(4)
imshow(open)

%% part 4
diameter = regionprops(open, 'MajorAxisLength')
figure(5)
# for doing a measurement myself and checking the answer
imshow(img)
d = imdistline;
```

my output for diameter is (and I dont know why it displays 7 times):

diameter =

255×1 struct array with fields:

```
MajorAxisLength
```

diameter =

255×1 struct array with fields:

```
MajorAxisLength
```

diameter =

255×1 struct array with fields:

```
MajorAxisLength
```

diameter =

255×1 struct array with fields:

```
MajorAxisLength
```

diameter =

255×1 struct array with fields:

```
Centroid
```

diameter =

255×1 struct array with fields:

```
MinorAxisLength
```

diameter =

255×1 struct array with fields:

```
MajorAxisLength
```

I would be happy to know how to fix it, thank you.

Comment: Where in your code do you apply a threshold? Looks like you use a gray-scale image in `regionprops`. Note that assigning 0 or 255 doesn’t make the image binary. You need to do `BW = img_grayscale >= 100`.

Comment: As Chris outlines `regionprops()` expects a binary `BW` image/logical array. To convert open from `uint8` to a logical array add this line to the top of part 4. `open = (open >= 100);`. This will create a logical array based on the threshold of 100.